# Como executar uma aplicação em Java com Play framework no prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilação, play-framework, prompt

Tenho um sistema de grande porte desenvolvido em `Java` que utiliza o `Play`, mas esse sistema foi desenvolvido no `Linux`, e agora preciso rodar ele no `Windows`. Existe um `script` para compilar no `Linux` (`run.sh.template`).

---

Preciso saber como fazer um `script` equivalente para `Windows` para que possa rodar no `prompt` do sistema.

**Script para Linux run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sample script to run the Playball server in the development environemnt

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)

source $BASEDIR/setenv.sh
play debug -Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf -Dlogger.file=conf/logback-dev.xml
```

**Script setenv.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xss4m -Xmx756m"
export JAVA_HOME="/data/dev/sdk/jdk1.7.0_67"
export PLAY_HOME="/data/dev/sdk/play/play-2.0.8"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PLAY_HOME:$PATH"
```

Comment: Adicione o código do script à pergunta, por favor.

Comment: É necessário ainda adicionar o código do setenv.sh.